# ext.net : Rebinding sqldatasource codebehind

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

By  using the example from http://examples.ext.net/#/Chart/Column/Basic/,i bind the my data to chart from my sqldatasource ,
but ,on this example ,there is a button called "ReloadData" that refresh the data,

like this way,

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void ReloadData(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        Store store = this.Chart1.GetStore();

        store.DataSource = Ext.Net.Examples.ChartData.GenerateData();
        store.DataBind();
    }
</script>
```

how can i bind again my sqldatasource inside the ReloadData method.

my simplified codes are here ;

chart.aspx

```
           <ext:Panel ID="Panel1" 
                runat="server"
                Layout="FitLayout" Flex="1">
                <TopBar>
                    <ext:Toolbar ID="Toolbar1" runat="server" Flex="1">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:Button ID="Button1" 
                                runat="server" 
                                Text="" 
                                Icon="ArrowRefresh" 
                                OnDirectClick="ReloadData" />
                            ......
                            ......

                        </Items>
                    </ext:Toolbar>
                </TopBar>
                <Items>                                                     
    <ext:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Shadow="true"  StyleSpec="background:#fff" Animate="true" ColumnWidth="0.5" Flex="1">
        <HtmlBin>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="datasource1"
 runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AProjeConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT COUNT(*)
                ....
                ....
                ">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </HtmlBin>

                            <Store>
                            <ext:Store ID="Store1" 
                                runat="server" 
                                DataSourceID="datasource1"
                                AutoDataBind="true">                           
                                <Model>
                                 .....
                             .....
                                </Model>
                            </ext:Store>
                        </Store>
       <Axes>
                            <ext:NumericAxis                             
                                Fields="O"                            
                                Grid="true"
                                Title="S"
                                Minimum="0">
                                <Label>
                        <Renderer Handler="return 
Ext.util.Format.number(value, '0,0');" />
                                </Label>
                            </ext:NumericAxis>                            

                            <ext:CategoryAxis 
                                Position="Bottom"
                                Fields="Ad"
                                Title=""
                                Width="75"
                                />                            
                        </Axes>
              <Series>
                            <ext:ColumnSeries 

                        ......
                        ......
                        ......
                            </ext:ColumnSeries>
                        </Series>
                        </ext:Chart>
    ......
    ......
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling just

```
Store1.DataBind();
```

should help.